# Shopify Dynamic Checkout Button adding incorrect variant on product page

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-template

I have tried to add the dynamic checkout button to the product pages but I'm having an issue where it doesn't matter what variant I select in the radio selection the variant that is pulled through to purchase is always the first available variant. The 'Add to cart' button works as expected.

Please see the code for the product page below, any guidance very much appreciated:

```
{% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
{% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}



{% assign mini_me = false %}
{% assign secret_santa = false %}
{% assign easter_egg = false %}
{% assign sustainable_cotton = false %}
{% assign wingwalker = false %}
{% assign clearance = false %}

{% for tag in product.tags %}

    {% if tag contains 'secret_santa' %}
        {% assign secret_santa = true %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if tag contains 'mini_me' %}
        {% assign mini_me = true %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if tag contains 'easter_egg' %}
        {% assign easter_egg = true %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if tag contains 'sustainable_cotton' %}
        {% assign sustainable_cotton = true %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if tag contains 'wingwalker_product' %}
        {% assign wingwalker = true %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if tag contains 'clear' %}
        {% assign clearance = true %}
    {% endif %}


{% endfor %}

<div class="block {% unless collection %}block--spaced{% endunless %} full-bleed product-wrap">

    <div class="wrapper">

        {% if collection %}
        {% capture label %}{{ 'general.labels.back_to'| t:  thing: collection.title  }}{% endcapture %}
        {% render 'back-btn', url: collection.url, text: label %}

        {% endif %}

        <div class="product">

            {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
    
            <div class="gallery product__gallery product__imgs stack">

                <div class="gallery__wrap">
        
                    <div id="product-gallery" class="gallery__imgs">

                        {% for image in product.images %}
                        <div class="product__img">

                            <figure class="frame frame--1x1">
                                {% comment %}<img src="{{ image | img_url: '1700x1700' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" width="1700" height="1700">{% endcomment %}
                                
                                <img    srcset="{{ image | img_url: '1700x1700' }} 1700w, 
                                                            {{ image | img_url: '1300x1300' }} 1300w, 
                                                            {{ image | img_url: '1000x1000' }} 1000w,
                                                            {{ image | img_url: '800x800' }} 800w" 
                                            sizes=" (max-width: 52.5rem) 100vw,
                                                            (max-width: 96rem) 50vw, 
                                                            855px"
                                            alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"
                                            width="1700" height="1700">

                            </figure>
                            
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    
                    </div>

                {% if mini_me %}
                    {% render 'mini-me' %}
                {% endif %}

                {% if sustainable_cotton %}
                    {% render 'sustainable-cotton' %}
                {% endif %}
            
                {% if easter_egg %}
                    {% render 'easter-egg' %}
                {% endif %}
            
                {% if secret_santa %}
                    {% render 'secret-santa' %}
                {% endif %}
            
                {% if wingwalker %}
                    {% render 'wingwalker' %}
                {% endif %}
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="overflow">

                    <div id="product-thumbnails" class="product__thumbs">

                

                    {% for image in product.images %}
                    <figure class="thumb">
                        {% assign matching_variant = '' %}
                        {% for var in product.variants %} 

                            {% if image contains var.featured_image %}
                            {% assign  matching_variant = matching_variant | append: var.id | append: ',' %}
                            {% endif %}

                        {% endfor %}
                        <button type="button" class="link link--no-border frame frame--1x1" data-matching-variants="{{ matching_variant }}">
                            <img data-src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" width="200" height="200" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" class="lazy">
                        </button>
                    </figure>
                    {% endfor %}

                    </div>

                </div>

                {% capture sale_text %}{{ 'general.labels.sale' | t }}{% endcapture %}

                {% if current_variant.compare_at_price and clearance%}
                    {% render 'sticker', text: sale_text %}
                {% endif %}
            
            </div>

            {% else %}

            <div class="product__imgs">
                <div class="product__img">
                    <figure class="frame frame--1x1">
                        <img data-src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '2048x2048' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg" class="lazy" width="2048" height="2048">

                            {% if mini_me %}
                            {% render 'mini-me' %}
                        {% endif %}
                    
                        {% if easter_egg %}
                            {% render 'easter-egg' %}
                        {% endif %}
                    
                        {% if secret_santa %}
                            {% render 'secret-santa' %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endif %}

            <div class="product__body">
                
                {% form 'product', product, id: "AddToCartForm", class: "stack" %}

                <input type="hidden" name="js-product" id="js-product" value='{{ product | json | escape }}'>
                <input type="hidden" name="js-money-format" id="js-money-format" value="{{ shop.money_format }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="sold-out-msg" id="sold-out-msg" value="{{ 'general.labels.sold_out' | t }}">
                {% assign number = '####' %}
                <input type="hidden" name="low-stock-msg" id="low-stock-msg" value="{{ 'product.limited_stock' | t: number: number }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="low-stock-threshold" id="low-stock-threshold" value="{{ settings.low_stock_threshold }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="max-qty" id="max-qty" value="{{ settings.cart_max_items }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="sku" id="sku" value="{{ product.variants.first.sku }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="load_more" value="{{ 'reviews.load_more' | t }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="add-to-cart-btn-text" name="add-to-cart-btn-text" value="{{ 'product.add_to_cart_button' | t }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="not-available-msg" name="not-available-msg" value="{{ 'product.not_available_msg' | t }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="error-msg" name="error-msg" value="{{ 'general.errors.something_went_wrong' | t }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="was-text" name="was-text" value="{{ 'general.labels.was' | t }}">

                {% assign skuQS = '' %}
                {% for variant in product.variants %}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ variant.id }}" value="{{ variant.inventory_quantity }}">
                {% if forloop.first == true %}
                    {% assign skuQS = skuQS | append: variant.sku %}
                {% else %}
                    {% assign skuQS = skuQS | append: ',' | append: variant.sku %}
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="hidden" id="sku-qs" value="{{ skuQS }}">


                    <select name="id" id="productSelect" data-productid="{{product.id}}">
                    {% for variant in product.variants %}
                        {% if variant.available %}
                            <option value="{{ variant.id }}">
                                {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
                            </option>
                        {% else %}
                            <option disabled="disabled">
                                {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'general.labels.sold_out' | t }}
                            </option>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    
                    <header class="flex pad-items justify-between align-baseline">
                        
                        {% render 'h', el: 'h1', classes: 'h2' text: product.title %}
                        
                        <div>
                            
                            <div class="stack">
        
                                <div class="flex justify-baseline">
                                    {% render 'price', price: current_variant.price, was_price: current_variant.compare_at_price, classes: 'text-right h3' %}
                                </div>
        
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
    
    
                    </header>

                    {% if settings.use_stampedio %}
                        <!-- Stamped - Begin Star Rating Badge -->
                        <span 
                        class="stamped-product-reviews-badge stamped-main-badge" 
                        data-id="{{ product.id }}" 
                        data-product-sku="{{ product.handle }}" 
                        data-product-title="{{product.title}}" 
                        data-product-type="{{product.type}}" 
                        style="display: block;">
                        {{product.metafields.stamped.badge}}
                        </span>
                        <!-- Stamped - End Star Rating Badge -->

                    {% endif %}

                    {% if settings.use_trustpilot %}

                        <div class="js-product-review-summary product-review-summary" hidden></div>

                    {% endif %}
                    
                    <div class="stack">
                            
                        <div class="box hidden shout bold" id="message" style="--box-bg: var(--color-white); --box-color: var(--color-red);--box-border-color: var(--color-white);">
                            <div class=" flex align-center pad-items">
                                {% render 'icon', icon: 'warning', classes: 'icon--m' %}
                                <span id="msg-text"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="stack js-options-wrap" hidden>

                        {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}

                        {% assign optionLoopIndex = forloop.index %}

                        <div>
                        
                            <fieldset id="ProductSelect-option-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="stack stack--xs {% unless option.values.size > 1 %}hidden{% endunless %}" name="{{ option.name | handleize }}" {% unless option.values.size > 1 %}hidden{% endunless %}>

                                {%- capture optionName -%}
                                    {%- if option.name == 'Size' or option.name == 'size' -%}
                                        {{ 'filter.size' | t }}

                                    {%- elsif option.name == 'Colour' or option.name == 'colour' or option.name == 'Color' or option.name == 'color' -%}

                                        {{ 'filter.colour' | t }}

                                    {%- else -%}

                                    {{ option.name }}

                                    {%- endif -%}
                                {%- endcapture -%}
                                <div class="flex justify-between align-end">
                                    <legend>
                                        {{ optionName | escape }}
                                    </legend>

                                    {% if option.name == 'Size' or option.name == 'size' %}
                                        <button class="link small" type="button" data-micromodal-trigger="size-guide-modal">{{ 'product.size_guide_link' | t }}</button>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <div class="radio-grid" id="js-product-radios">

                                        

                                    {%- for value in option.values -%}
                        
                                        {%- assign variant_label_state = true -%}

                                            {%- unless product.variants[forloop.index0].available  -%}
                                                {%- assign variant_label_state = false -%}
                                            {%- endunless -%}

                                            {% if product.options_with_values[1].values.size > 1 %}
                                            {%- assign variant_label_state = true -%}
                                            {% endif %}

                                            

                                        <div class="radio">
                                            <input type="radio"
                                                {% if option.selected_value == value %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
                                                {% unless variant_label_state %} disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}
                                                value="{{ value | escape }}"
                                                data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}"
                                                data-option-group="option{{ optionLoopIndex }}"
                                                name="{{ option.name | handleize }}"
                                                id="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape | handleize }}">

                                            {% capture for_attr %}for="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape | handleize }}" {% unless variant_label_state %}disabled{% endunless %}{% endcapture %}

                                            {% capture label_text %}{{ value  | escape | replace: 'Months', 'M' | replace: 'Years', 'Y' | replace: ' to ', ' - ' | replace: "1/2", '<span><sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub></span>' }}{% endcapture %}
                                            {% assign variant_arr = label_text | split: " " %}

                                            {% if variant_arr.size > 1  %}
                                                {% unless variant_arr contains '<span><sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub></span>' %}
                                                {% assign variant_arr_length = variant_arr | size | minus: 1 %}
                                                    {% assign unit_label =  variant_arr | last %}

                                                    {% comment %}Need to check if the value is a number - if it is don't trim it. If it isn't, its a string (like MONTH) so do trim it {% endcomment %}
                                                    {% assign isNum = unit_label | times: 1 %}
                                                    {% if isNum == 0 %}
                                                    {% assign unit_initial = unit_label | slice: 0 | upcase %}
                                                    {% else %}
                                                    {% assign unit_initial = unit_label %}
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                    {% assign variant_size = variant_arr | slice: 0, variant_arr_length | join: " " %}
                                                    
                                                    {% capture label_text %}{{ variant_size | replace: " to ", " - " }} {{ unit_initial }}{% endcapture %}
                                                {% endunless %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        
                                            {% render 'btn', el: 'label', text: label_text, attributes: for_attr, classes: 'btn--small' %}
                                        </div>
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                        </div>
                        
                        {%- endfor -%}

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.js-options-wrap -->

                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <hr>

                    <div class="flex align-center  justify-between">
                        <label for="Quantity">{{ 'general.labels.quantity' | t }}</label>
                        
                        {% render 'number-stepper', id: 'Quantity', max: settings.cart_max_items %}
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn btn--full">{{ 'product.add_to_cart_button' | t }}</button>
                    {{ form | payment_button }}
                    
                    {% unless current_variant.available %}
                    <a class="klaviyo-bis-trigger btn" href="#">Notify Me When Available</a>
                    {% endunless %}
                    
                    
                    <div id="pd-native-delivery-modal">
                        <div class="flex justify-center pad-items" style="--pad-items-gap: var(--size-0);">
                            {% capture free_delivery_amount %}{{ settings.cart_free_price | money | remove: '.00' | remove: ',00' }}{% endcapture %}
                            {% capture free_delivery_text %}
                            {{ 'product.free_delivery_text' | t: amount: free_delivery_amount  }}
                            {% endcapture %}
                            {% render 'icon', icon: 'delivery', label: free_delivery_text %}
                            <button class="link small" type="button" data-micromodal-trigger="delivery-modal">{{ 'general.labels.more_info' | t }}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    

                    <hr>
                    <article class="stack">
    
                        <div class="rte stack">
                            {{ product.description }}
                        </div>
                        
                        <hr>
    
                        <div>
    
                            <p class="dt">
                                <button type="button" class="toggle flex justify-between align-center">{{ 'product.product_details_title' | t }}
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                                        <rect class="vert" height="8" width="2" y="1" x="4"/>
                                        <rect height="2" width="8" y="4" x="1"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </p>

                            <ul class="dl">

                                <!-- COLOUR -->
                                {% for tag in product.tags %}
                                {% if tag contains '_colour' %}
                                {% assign curr_tag = tag | replace: '_colour', '' %}
                                    <li class="dd">{{ curr_tag }}</li>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}

                                <!-- MATERIAL -->
                                {% for tag in product.tags %}
                                {% if tag contains '_material' %}
                                {% assign curr_tag = tag | replace: '_material', '' %}
                                    <li class="dd">{{ curr_tag }}</li>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}

                                <!-- CARE -->
                                {% assign care = '' %}
                                {% for tag in product.tags %}
                                    {% if tag contains '_care' %}
                                            {% assign care = care | append: tag %}
                                            {% assign care = care | append: '|' %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}

                                {% assign careArr = care | split: '|' %}

                                {% if careArr.size > 0 %}
                  <li class="dt">
                    {% for care in careArr %}
                    {{ settings.[care] }}{% unless forloop.last %}, {% endunless %}
                    {% endfor %}
                                    </li>
                  {% endif %}

                                <!-- WARNING -->
                                {% for tag in product.tags %}
                                {% if tag contains '_warning' %}
                                {% assign curr_tag = tag | replace: '_warning', '' %}
                                    <li class="dd">{{ 'product.detail.warning_title' | t }}: {{ curr_tag }}</li>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}

                                
                                <!-- COUNTRY OF ORIGIN -->
                                {% for tag in product.tags %}
                                {% if tag contains '_country_of_origin' %}
                                {% assign curr_tag = tag | replace: '_country_of_origin', '' %}
                                    <li class="dd">{{ 'product.detail.origin_title' | t }} {{ curr_tag }}</li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
    
                        </div>
                        
                        <hr>
    
                    </article>
                {% endform %}



        </div>
        <!-- /.product__body -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.product -->

    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.block -->

{% section 'mini-me-products' %}

{% section 'related-products' %}

{% section 'recommended-products' %}


{% assign i = 1 %}
{% assign mainCharColl = '' %}
{% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% if tag contains '_mainCharacter' %}
        {% assign mainCharColl = tag | replace: '_mainCharacter', '' | handleize %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign relatedTags = '' %}

<div class="block block--spaced" id="related-characters">
    <div class="stack">

        {% capture related_character_title %}{{ 'product.related_character_title'| t  }}{% endcapture %}

        {% render 'h', el: 'h2', classes: 'text-center', text: related_character_title %}

        <div class="flex-grid">

            {% for tag in collections.[mainCharColl].tags %}

                {% if tag contains '_character' and i <= 3 %}

                    {% assign character = tag | replace: '_character', '' | handleize %}

                    {% if collections.[character].products_count > 0 %}
                        {% unless character == mainCharColl %}
                            {% assign relatedTags = relatedTags | append: character %}
                            {% assign relatedTags = relatedTags | append: '|' %}
                            {% assign i = i | plus: 1 %}
                        {% endunless %}
                    {% endif %}

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

            {% assign relatedTags = relatedTags | prepend: '|' %}
            {% assign relatedTags = relatedTags | prepend: mainCharColl %}
            {% assign relatedArr = relatedTags | split: '|' %}
            {% assign relatedArrLen = relatedArr | size %}

            {% if relatedArrLen > 0 %}

                {% for character in relatedArr %}
                
                    {% render 'collection-card', collection: collections.[character] %}

                {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}

        </div>

    </div>
    
</div>

{% if settings.use_stampedio %}
    <!--Stamped - Begin Main Widget -->
    <div 
    id="stamped-main-widget"   
    data-product-id="{{ product.id }}"   
    data-name="{{ product.title | escape }}"   
    data-url="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}"   
    data-image-url="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: "large" |replace: '?', '%3F' | replace: '&','%26'}}" 
    data-description="{{ product.description | escape }}"   
    data-product-sku="{{product.handle}}"
    data-product-title="{{product.title}}" 
    data-product-type="{{product.type}}">   
    {{product.metafields.stamped.reviews}}   
    </div>
    <!-- Stamped - End Main Widget -->

{% endif %}

{% if settings.use_trustpilot %}

<div class="block block--spaced js-review-block" hidden>

    <div class="stack">

        <div class="center">
    
            <div class="stack align-center">
                {% render 'h', el: 'h2', text: 'What Our Customers Think' %}
    
                <span class="h h2 js-review-block-summary"></span>
    
                <p class="small js-review-based-label"></p>
    
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="review-grid js-review-grid">

        </div>

        <div class="js-load-more flex justify-center" hidden>
            <button class="btn btn--center" type="button" data-fetch-url="">{{ 'reviews.load_more' | t }}</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{% endif %}
```

I'm not sure what to do to rectify, for now I have just removed the dynamic button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the value of the variant id each time a variant is changed.
You will have an input with the name of id.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id"  value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant }}"
```

After finding this input field, you will have to update it's value using Javascript whenever the radio is changed. Whatever variant is selected, grab its id and put that in hidden input's value. When a form is submitted, liquid looks for this input and posts the variant associated with that id.